# c, using strtok and strcat together

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok, strcat

I am creating my own shell using c but I keep getting an error, which I believe involves using `strtok` and `strcat`. Note that `path` and `userInput` are global strings.

```
int myFunction()
{
    char *possiblePaths = getenv(PATH);

    path = strtok(possiblePaths,":");
    path = strcat(path,"/");
    path = strcat(path, userInput);

    while(path != NULL)
    {
        //other code

        path = strtok(NULL,":");
        path = strcat(path,"/");
        path = strcat(path, userInput);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

getenv gives me a string,

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

What I then want to do is tokenize the string based on `':'`, then concatenate `'/'` plus the my global variable `userInput`.  The output should look like,

```
/opt/local/bin/userInput
```

Then the next time though the loop I would get

```
/opt/local/sbin/userInput
```

Unfortunately I get the following

```
/opt/local/bin/userInput
userInput/userInput
/userInput/userInput
/userInput/userInput
```

My first `strtok` and `strcat` give me the correct result. But then `/userInput` will keep looping until I hit a segmentation fault.  I'm pretty sure my error has to do with mixing up pointers using `strtok` and `strcat` but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: *"Note that path and userInput are global strings"* - Don't ask us to note anything. Put their definitions explicitly in your [mcve].

Comment: You shouldn't hack the string returned by `getenv()` — you're modifying the PATH environment of your shell.  That might not matter if you're careful (but it probably does — you'd have to use `execve()` or similar, and explicitly set a safe PATH value), but you're likely to need to take a copy and work with that.

Comment: Also, when you do use `strcat()`, you're overwriting the next segment of the PATH with what you concatenate.  You need to rethink what you're doing — work out where your string operations are reading and writing.  At the moment, you have a mess.

Comment: Your `strcat` calls overwrite the space that you are planning to read from with the next `strtok`.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "strings" and "pointers" which are two very different (though related) concepts in C.  You need to go back and reread your intro to C text.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (7.22.4.6 The getenv function)

> 4. ... The string pointed to **shall not be modiﬁed** by the program

And the standard C function `strtok` changes the original string passed to the function as argument.

You could use instead standard C function `strchr` to find the character `':'` and then copy the found string in a character array using another standard function `memcpy` and then append it with required strings.